# Replace first comma with a semicolon into a string using R and regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I would like to replace only the first comma in my dataset with a semicolon using  R, regex, and, possibly, the library `stringr`.

The following one is an extract of my dataset:

```
mydata <- structure(list(SURNAME_Name = c("AASSVE Arnstein", "ABATECOLA Gianpaolo", 
    "ABATEMARCO Antonio", "ABBAFATI Cristiana", "ABBATE Tindara", 
    "ABBRUZZO Antonino", "ABRARDI Laura", "ABRATE Graziano", "ACCONCIA Antonio", 
    "ACHARD Paola Olimpia", "ADAMO Rosa", "ADAMO Stefano", "ADDA Jerome Frans", 
    "ADDABBO Tindara", "ADDIS Elisabetta", "ADDIS Michela", "ADELFIO Giada", 
    "ADIGUZEL Feray", "ADIMARI Gianfranco", "DE MARCHI Maria Paola")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I performed this code to insert a comma between SURNAME and Names and then I tried replacing the first comma with a semicolon:

```
library(stringr)    
mydata %>% 
mutate(Name_delimited=str_replace_all(string=SURNAME_Name,pattern="(\\s)(?=[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)",replacement="\\,"),
       Name_delimited1=str_replace_all(string=Name_delimited,pattern="\\1(\\,)(?=[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)",replacement="\\;"))
```

But it doesn't work as I expected because, for example, the row number 10 in my dataset remains `ACHARD,Paola,Olimpia` instead of `ACHARD;Paola,Olimpia` and for row number 20 where I expected `DE MARCHI;Maria,Paola` instead of `DE MARCHI,Maria,Paola`

Any hints are wellcome

Comment: Try `str_replace_all(str_replace(mydata$SURNAME_Name, "\\s+", ";"), "\\s+", ",")`

Comment: It works only when there are no double SURNAME, I don't think it works for example with "DE MARCHI Antonio"

Comment: Are you changing the requirements? There is no `DE MARCHI Antonio` in your sample data. What is the rule here?

Comment: Sorry, I am going to change my dataset to report special cases of double SURNAME

Comment: Ok, but what is the requirement in that case? How do you match such surnames and what should be the expected result? Please add it all to the question.

Comment: I fixed the question

Comment: You have not mentioned in which context(s) spaces should be preserved. Only between `DE` and the next word?

Comment: It is implicitly considered by the first "str_replace_all(string=SURNAME_Name,pattern="(\\s)(?=[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)",replacement="\\,")", because the SURNAMES are always written with uppercases, while the Names have only the first character with an uppercase

Comment: So, all whitespaces between ALLCAPS should be kept, right?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, many thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may replace the first whitespace(s) with `;` using `str_replace` and then use `str_replace_all` to replace all other spaces with `,`:

```
> str_replace_all(str_replace(mydata$SURNAME_Name, "\\s+", ";"), "\\s+", ",")
 [1] "AASSVE;Arnstein"      "ABATECOLA;Gianpaolo"  "ABATEMARCO;Antonio"  
 [4] "ABBAFATI;Cristiana"   "ABBATE;Tindara"       "ABBRUZZO;Antonino"   
 [7] "ABRARDI;Laura"        "ABRATE;Graziano"      "ACCONCIA;Antonio"    
[10] "ACHARD;Paola,Olimpia" "ADAMO;Rosa"           "ADAMO;Stefano"       
[13] "ADDA;Jerome,Frans"    "ADDABBO;Tindara"      "ADDIS;Elisabetta"    
[16] "ADDIS;Michela"        "ADELFIO;Giada"        "ADIGUZEL;Feray"      
[19] "ADIMARI;Gianfranco"   "ADINOLFI;Paola"
```

Note you may replace `str_replace` with `sub` and `str_replace_all` with `gsub` and use

```
gsub("\\s+", ",", sub("\\s+", ";", mydata$SURNAME_Name))
```

relying on sole base R functions.

**To preserve whitespaces inside ALLCAPS surnames**, use

```
> reg <- "(*UCP)\\b\\p{Lu}+(?:\\s+\\p{Lu}+)+\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\\s+"
> gsub(reg, ",", sub(reg, ";", mydata$SURNAME_Name, perl=TRUE), perl=TRUE)
 [1] "AASSVE;Arnstein"       "ABATECOLA;Gianpaolo"   "ABATEMARCO;Antonio"    "ABBAFATI;Cristiana"   
 [5] "ABBATE;Tindara"        "ABBRUZZO;Antonino"     "ABRARDI;Laura"         "ABRATE;Graziano"      
 [9] "ACCONCIA;Antonio"      "ACHARD;Paola,Olimpia"  "ADAMO;Rosa"            "ADAMO;Stefano"        
[13] "ADDA;Jerome,Frans"     "ADDABBO;Tindara"       "ADDIS;Elisabetta"      "ADDIS;Michela"        
[17] "ADELFIO;Giada"         "ADIGUZEL;Feray"        "ADIMARI;Gianfranco"    "DE MARCHI;Maria,Paola"
```

The regex engine is now PCRE, and I added a `(*UCP)` PCRE verb to make `\b` Unicode aware, and an `\\b\\p{Lu}+(?:\\s+\\p{Lu}+)+\\b(*SKIP)(*F)` alternative that matches any whitespace-separated ALLCAPS letter words as whole words and then *skips* these matches keeping whitespace intact.

**Details**

- `(*UCP)` - makes `\b` in this pattern Unicode aware
- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `\\p{Lu}+` - 1+ Unicode uppercase letters
- `(?:\\s+\\p{Lu}+)+` - 1 or more occurrences of 1+ whitespaces and then 1+ Unicode letters
- `\\b`  - word boundary
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - PCRE verbs that discard the matched text and proceed looking for the next match starting from the location where the previous search ended
- `|` - or
- `\\s+` - 1+ whitespaces in any other context.

Comment: Why load an external package? With *your* regex and chained replacements, `gsub("\\s+", ",", sub("\\s+", ";", SURNAME_Name))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Sure, these are equivalent methods.

Comment: Just another note: if the PCRE pattern does not work, a `gsubfn` solution might help: `library(gsubfn)` and then `sub(",", ";", gsubfn("\\y([[:upper:]]+(?:[[:space:]]+[[:upper:]]+)+)\\y|[[:space:]]+", function(x,y) ifelse(nchar(x)>0, x, ","), mydata$SURNAME_Name), fixed=TRUE)` that uses Tcl regex library.